# How can I convert a string into unicode string in Perl

Tags: perl, unicode

how convert string into Unicode string in Perl.

I am looking some attribute in LDAP which accepts only Unicode string .

So i want to convert normal string to Unicode string

Comment: Can you elaborate on your question? What is your actual goal and what problem have you hit with your attempts?

Comment: Some sample code (with a description of how it is not working) would be advantageous to your cause.

Comment: before you post more questions, please read through http://www.catb.org/~esr/faqs/smart-questions.html. Your recent downvotes are indications of the lack of clarity of your questions. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're using Perl 5.8.0 or newer, Perl strings **are** Unicode strings.  If you have a string in some other encoding, look at the [Encode](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Encode) module and the [:encoding](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?PerlIO::encoding) layer.  You can get a list of the supported encodings in your Perl with `perldoc Encode::Supported`.

**Edit:**

How are you accessing the LDAP server?  If you're using [Net::LDAP](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Net::LDAP), then you probably want to use the `raw => REGEX` option.  Any LDAP attribute that matches REGEX is treated as a binary string.  All other attributes get handled as Unicode strings.